# Reset position of view after animate().translationYBy()

Tags: android, android-animation

I try to program an intro, which shows users, that they can press a long click on the different `ListView` entries.
In order to do so, I animate an index finger going up towards one of these entries, and clicks. After the animation, I want it to be in the initial position again, so I can replay the animation.
I tried it with `getLocationInWindow` before the animation, and than `setTop()` on animation end, but it didn't do anything. To just reverse the animation isn't working either, since this just results in an infinite loop of `onAnimationEnd` calls.
This is my code without my tries:

```
//Animations
        tapfFinger.animate().translationYBy(-StaticHelper.dpToPx(95)).setDuration(1500).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationStart(animation);
                textViewLongClickDemo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textViewLongClickDemo.setAlpha(0);
                textViewLongClickDemo.animate().setDuration(800).alpha(1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(final Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                tapfFinger.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tap);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        imageViewLongClickDemoContextMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tapfFinger.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        textViewLongClickDemo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        demoListEntry.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tranparent));
                        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageViewLongClickDemoContextMenu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                tapfFinger.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tap_before);
                                tapfFinger.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                playLongClickDemoAnimations();
                            }
                        }, 1200);
                    }
                }, 1200);

            }
        });
```